# What happen if handler.post(runnable) very fast

Tags: android, runnable

I use handler.post(runnable) to post a runnable to a queue associated with a thread.
What happen if I post the runnable very fast and make the queue full?

Thanks.

YL

Comment: You will run out of memory and the application will terminate.

Comment: How to avoid this situation?

Comment: Well, you should go into more detail about your use case. I thought you were asking a question out of simple academic curiosity. The simplest solution is: "don't do that". If you need to accomplish a task N times on this thread, you can simply have the Runnable loop N times (internally), instead of queueing it N times.

Comment: Let's say I have one thread A, which post a runnable to another thread B via its handler every 10 ms. It takes 100 ms to run a runnable in thread B. Sooner or later I think the queue of thread B will be full, right?

Comment: Yes. Per your description, you're assigning thread B work items at a rate 10x higher than it can prosecute them. Intuitively, you'd expect that this will eventually cause you to exhaust some resource; in this case, it is memory.

Comment: How to deal with this situation? Let thread B execute the runnable with a rate faster than that thread A post the runnable?

Comment: See my second comment.